# I wanted to print factorial of no. using recursion but its not working in C

Tags: c, recursion

```
#include <stdio.h>

int factorial(int b)
{
    return (b * factorial(b - 1));
}

int main()
{
    int num;
    printf("Enter a no:\n");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    printf("factorial is %d\n", factorial(num));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are missing a base case.

Comment: The `factorial()` function will recurse until your stack is exhausted. You do not want it to recurse any further when `b <= 1`, not accounting for negative factorials

Comment: I removed the C++ tag, C++ is not C they are different languages

Comment: @PepijnKramer However, the program is both valid C *and* C++

Comment: Apart from "not working" presumably meaning "stack overflow", the use of `int` limits the utility to **12!**.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a base case. Also, you don't want negative numbers to be input, so make the function arguments and return type to be of `unsigned int`.

A base case is a condition to end the recursion. Since it wasn't present, the program was executing even for negative values of `b`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned int factorial(unsigned int b)
{
    if (b <= 1)
    {
        return b;
    }
    return (b * factorial(b - 1));
}

int main()
{
    int num;
    printf("Enter a no:\n");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    printf("factorial is %u\n", factorial(num));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks bro for ur help , I got one more question: When we are using "unsigned int factorial(unsigned int b)" we will get Non negative input as well as output, so why there is  still need to use "if (b <= 1){ return b; }".

Comment: Because, 1! = 1 and 0! = 1.